# How to convert Image to byteArray

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an android app, and I use this method to convert my photo taken from the camera

```
      public fun imageToBitmap(image: Bitmap): ByteArray 
   {
        val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream)
        return stream.toByteArray()
    }
```

but when I try to upload my converted photo 'byteArray' to the API I get this error

```
{
 "errors": {
"": [
  "Unexpected end when deserializing object. Path '', line 1, position 855."
],
"photo_.pphoto": [
  "The supplied value is invalid."
]
```

I'm using asp.Net API with SQL server database and the phototype in the database is varBinary(Max)
-the Upload to the API success pre-converted images samples (using this site https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter " but it's not working with photo converter using my method.
I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Base64 encode your `byte[]` data.

```kotlin
    private fun getBase64String(array: ByteArray) = Base64.encodeToString(array, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

Called code:

```kotlin
   getBase64String(imageToBitmap(..))
```